# ASP.net EF Code First - 2 tables 

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ef-code-first

*(ASP.net MCV 3 Razor View)*

Hey, my problem is this:

I have in the models 2 classes, one called X, one called Y.
**X has a property for class Y.**

Now, I seeded them and I have a database with 2 tables for each. I need to use both of them in a single page so I passed them with a 3rd class that contains 2 IQueryables properties for each X and Y.

Now, in a page (.cshtml), I made 2 lists, one for X.ToList(), and one for Y.ToList(). I can reach this way both X and Y.

The problem is here, the value of Y **inside X** is null! Why?! it's so frustrating I spent so much time thinking what's wrong but I came up with nothing!

Comment: can you post the relevant code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, the code that reads X doesn't Include() Y.